# Unable to list files with GoogleDrive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to get a list of documents from google drive via its SDK.  I use the service account to accomplish the authentication, and set the scope to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive which has the full permission.

However, the response contains an empty item list though there do have test files in my google drive.

```
        AuthorizationServerDescription desc = GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description;
        X509Certificate2 key = new X509Certificate2(m_file, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        string scope = Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService.Scopes.Drive.ToString().ToLower();
        AssertionFlowClient client = new AssertionFlowClient(desc, key) { ServiceAccountId = m_email, Scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/" + scope };

        OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient> auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(client, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);


        DriveService service = new DriveService(auth);

        FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();
        request.Q = "";
        Stream dataStream = request.FetchAsStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Nivco's answer to [Google Drive SDK: Empty array of files returned from Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484462/google-drive-sdk-empty-array-of-files-returned-from-drive/13484913) for more details about your issue.

You're basically listing the files in the service account's Drive and not yours. What you need to do is setup the email for the user of the domain you are trying to impersonate, check the Google Drive SDK documentation for instructions and sample code showing how to do it:

https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

Comment: Thanks Claudio.  I'm a newbee to this Google Drive SDK.  It seems that I must be an admin of a particular domain to setup the delegation which I couldn't.  What I want to do is setting up a service to download my document from Google Drive to a local DB, there should be no GUI to obtain the authentication.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to go through the OAuth flow at least once to approve the app, but then you can store the refresh token forever and use it to generate new access tokens with no user interaction: https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth